# How do I reference the variable declared under a class in Python?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-2.x

I am relatively new to Python and I am using Python 2.7.x

I have a question regarding namespaces in Python:

```
class Team():
    x = 2 
    def p(self):
        print x 

a = Team()
a.p()
```

When I run the code, it says `global x is not defined`. Shouldn't `x` belong to the `Team` object? My goal is to create a `Team` class where `x` has a default value of 2.

In Java it would be something like:

```
class Team()
{
    int x = 2;
}

a = new Team();
```

Comment: you should be calling it as `self.x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an instance attribute and a default value of 2 :

```
class Team(object): # use object for new style classes 
    def __init__(self, x=2):
        self.x = x # use self to refer to the instance

    def p(self):
        print self.x # self.x 

a = Team()
a.p()
2

b = Team(4) # give b a different value for x
b.p()
4
```

Difference between  [class vs instance attributes](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php)

[new vs old style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

Comment: why didnt you create x at the class level ? solid answer none the less (ahh the edit makes it more clear that you are probably correctly anticipating his use case)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I was going to link to an answer showing the difference between class an instance attributes, I just thought doing it this way was more obvious.

Comment: Quick note, you may want to inherit from `object` since this is on python2.x

Comment: Don't forget `object` in Python 2, old-style classes are rarely used.

Comment: I guess I really  needed  to add object :)

Comment: @aceminer, no worries,  there is some info worth reading in the links I added.

Answer (score 1):

If you want make x as class variable, just try this way:

```
class Team(object):
    x = 2 
    def __init__(self):
      pass

print Team.x
Team.x = 3
print Team.x
```

You don't need to instance to get the value and you can change it as you want.

If you want to make the num as instance property, you have to use self(like this in Java):

```
class Team(object):

  def __init__(self, num):
    self.num = num

  def get_num(self):
    return self.num

  def set_num(self, change_num):
    self.num = change_num

t1 = Team(2)
print t1.get_num()
t1.set_num(3)
print t1.get_num()
```

Comment: Do you need __init__ explicitly if it's just passing?